# Modify get/set values populated by JSON C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm retriving JSON objects in C# by using Json.NET. I have a class file with objects like:

```
public class Items
{   
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string _external; // not fetched from JSON
}
```

However, I'd like to know how to do the following also for later projects, as it should be very basic, but after a few hours of searching and trying, I'm not getting it to work;

If the **url** string has a value, I want to modify the **external** method to contain a value similar to **"yes"**. I've tried a few different methods, and just to show you how it should not be done:

```
    public string url_check
    {
        set
        {
            if (url == "")
            {
                this._external= "";
            }
            else if (url != "")
            {
                this._external= "[external]";
            }
        }

    }
```

How should I achieve this in a way which actually works?

Comment: Well thats all a bit confusing? Am I being dumb here or does that question make no sense? Whats 'url' got to do with Json.Net, whats any of that code got to do with Json.Net?

Comment: From former experience from posting here, people want different information. I simply added it so that no one would have to ask.

Comment: tbh, I'd say you've not added enough detail not too much...

Comment: Understandable, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public string url_check
{
    set
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            this._external= "";
        }
        else
        {
            this._external= "[external]";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Alright. I'm trying to bind _external to a textblock, but nothing shows up, and in debug mode it simply says "could not evaluate expression" on that field. Any ideas?